# How do locate and use programs that are available on the computer by default?

Tags: g++

I wanted to locate g++ on ubuntu. However when I type it in the dash's search, it says that nothing matches my search. Where exactly can I access  such programs on ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0):

The Dash only searches for GUI programs.

To use a command line program like `g++` open a Terminal, either using the Dash or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, and call the program there.

Comment: What do you mean by "call the program"?.What's the command for this

Comment: he means to launch the program

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

1. open terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. enter `which [name]` (replace [name] with whatever you want)
3. This 'which' will show you where the eecutable is saved. (something similar to `/usr/bin[name]`)
4. If no message is displayed it isn't installed.

To execute the programm enter `[name]` (replace `[name]` again with whatever you want)

I know there might be a easier way, to check which programm is installed!

Comment: what do you mean by replace g++, and the starting program?

Comment: I typed  in this command just now and it gave me /usr/bin/g++. I typed in this in the terminal and it gave me: fatal error  no input files
compilation terminated. What does this mean

Comment: the message `/usr/bin/g++` tells you that g++ is installed

Comment: Ok so how do i run it?

Comment: just type in the terminal [name]

Comment: I did that. I typed in g++, and it says :  fatal error: no input files. Cant I run it like a normal C++ compiler?

Comment: you must add options... mostly you can use `-h` or `--help`